# How to insert JSON data into Payload for API deployment?

Tags: python, json, api

Need to have JSON file contents inserted inside {} for Payload. Unable to do this successfully. Any thoughts?

Attempted to write the JSON file contents as a string, this failed. Attempted to insert JSON file into payload = {}, failed.

```
import requests, meraki, json, os, sys

with open('networkid.txt') as file:
     array = file.readlines()
     for line in array:
         line = line.rstrip("\n")
         url = 'https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/%s/alertSettings' %line
         payload = {}
         headers = { 'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': 'API Key','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
         response = requests.request('PUT', url, headers = headers, data = payload, allow_redirects=True, timeout = 10)
         print(response.text)
```

I am writing a script to deploy parameters to Meraki networks via API. I have the JSON information formatted correctly and in its own file and what I am needing is to insert the JSON data into the location of Payload in the script. Any ideas on how to do this? I already have a for loop which is necessary to run a list of network ID's contained in a .txt file. Any thoughts?

Comment: you said you attempted to write/insert...put I don't see anywhere where you actually do that. you set `payload = {}`, but do nothing with that. I'm also assuming your indents are off, as I'm thinking you don't want to use requests after each iteration of your for loop.

Comment: This code will produce a syntax error because of the indentation. Please fix it. When you paste code into a question or answer, you can immediately select the pasted code and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the interface to have it properly formatted for you.

Comment: Just corrected the format. The code as is works perfectly for other uses we make of it, but I am not 100% how to insert a JSON file. That is what I am asking help for.

Comment: Have you tried json.load to read the json data in your file?

Comment: I am attempting to right now actually. I am not a python expert so forgive me. I am trying to figure out where to place that actually. I need the For loop and with statement to stay as they are because they perform a totally different function which is necessary for this whole thing to work. I am unsure of where to place your suggestion in this code at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` parameter in `requests.request` takes `(optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:Request`.

You can convert your properly formatted json file to a python dictionary using json.load:

```
with open('json_information.json') as f:
    payload = json.load(f)
```

Then you can directly pass `data=payload` into the call to `requests.request`:

```
with open('networkid.txt') as file:
    array = file.readlines()
    for line in array:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        url = 'https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/%s/alertSettings' % line
        headers = { 'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': 'API Key','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.request('PUT',
                                    url,
                                    headers=headers,
                                    data=payload,
                                    timeout = 10)  # allow_redirects is True by default
        print(response.text)
```